# When sorting an array of objects, is it possible to further group items that have been pushed to the bottom, using sort()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm doing this in JavaScript and I have to do it within a single sort() function as it's being sent as a param.

For example, I have objects that have I sort by category and then I further sort by sub category using:

```
return item1.category.localeCompare(item2.category) : item1.subCategory.localeCompare(item2.subCategory)
```

But for objects that have no category I push to the bottom using:

```
    if(item1.category == ''){
        res = 1
    }
    if(item2.category == ''){
        res = -1
    }
```

The problem with this is that all those items are all together at the bottom but they're all jumbled up and what I need is for them to be grouped together by subcategory.

Example of objects as I can sort them now:

```
[
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'}
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat2'}
]
```

Which I need to become:

```
[
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat1', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'cat2', 'subcategory':'subcat2'}
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat1'},
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat2'},
  {'category':'', 'subcategory':'subcat2'}
]
```

Comment: Please show all your code relevant to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort first the empty parts to bottom and then with a compare the strings. Take both for `category` and `subcategory`.

```js
var data = [{ category: 'cat2', subcategory: 'subcat1' }, { category: 'cat1', subcategory: 'subcat1' }, { category: 'cat2', subcategory: 'subcat2' }, { category: '', subcategory: '' }, { category: '', subcategory: 'subcat1' }, { category: '', subcategory: 'subcat2' }, { category: 'cat1', subcategory: 'subcat2' }, { category: 'cat1', subcategory: '' }, { category: 'cat2', subcategory: '' }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (
        !a.category - !b.category ||                 // move falsy values to bottom
        a.category.localeCompare(b.category) ||      // sort strings
        !a.subcategory - !b.subcategory || 
        a.subcategory.localeCompare(b.subcategory) 
    );
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this dynamically by using a helper function and sort in a nested fashion for as many properties as you like.

```js
function getFakeObjects(n){  // helper function to get test objects
  return Array(n).fill()
                 .reduce(o => o.concat({p1 : String.fromCharCode(...Array(5).fill().map(_ => ~~(Math.random()*26)+97)),
                                        p2 : ~~(Math.random()*5)+1,
                                        p3 : ["Istanbul","Moscow","New York","Tokyo","Rio","Accra"][~~(Math.random()*6)],
                                        p4 : ~~(Math.random()*2+1)+String.fromCharCode(~~(Math.random()*3)+65)
                                       }),[]);
}

function multiLevelSorter(os,ps){
  return os.sort(function(a,b){
                   var p = ps.find(f => a[f] !== b[f]);
                   return a[p] < b[p] ? -1 : 1;
                 });
}

var fakes = getFakeObjects(50),
sortOrder = ["p3","p2","p4","p1"],
   sorted = multiLevelSorter(fakes,sortOrder);
sorted.forEach(o => console.log("{p1:", o.p1,"p2:",o.p2,"p3:",o.p3,"p4:",o.p4,"}"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

So the above code sorts in the priorities of p3 -> p2 -> p4 -> p1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SortedArrayCategory. The code is follow

//arrTemp = Your actual array name.

```
                                self.sortedArrayCategory = arrTemp.sortedArrayUsingComparator {
                                    (obj1, obj2) -> NSComparisonResult in

                                    let p1 = obj1 as! String
                                    let p2 = obj2 as! String
                                    let result = p1.compare(p2)
                                    return result
                                }
```